# Using SES on a different region from EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ses, region

The region my EC2 instance is in is not supported by SES, can I still somehow send emails through another region?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, you can actually call AWS services *in* any region *from* any region. In fact, you can call AWS services **from anywhere on the Internet** (such as your own home computer).

If you are using Amazon SES [via SMTP](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-email-smtp.html), just point to the SES SMTP endpoint.

If you are using Amazon SES [via API calls](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-email-api.html), pass the Region Name to the client. For example, in Python:

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('ses', region_name='us-east-1')
client.send_email(...)
```